# in c# Read full txt file

Tags: c#

I tried to do a form application and I have a problem about use StreamReader feature. in StreamWriter feature, I did it but StreamReader just read the last line and The txt file contains, in many rows for example: names and phone numbers but like I said the code read last line

```
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //1

        StreamWriter sw;
        sw = File.AppendText("metinbelgesi.txt");
       sw.Write(textBox1.Text + " ");
        sw.Write(textBox2.Text + " ");
        sw.WriteLine(textBox3.Text+"." );


        sw.Flush();
        sw.Close();

    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (File.Exists("metinbelgesi.txt"))
        {
             FileStream fs = new FileStream("metinbelgesi.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            StreamReader sw = new StreamReader(fs);

            //sw = File.AppendText("metinbelgesi.txt");
            string yazi = sw.ReadLine();
            while (yazi != null)
            {

                richTextBox1.Text = yazi;

            }

            sw.Close();
            fs.Close();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("First, You Join.");

        }
    }
```

What do I do?

Comment: You've put a while loop over a condition that's going to either always be false or always be true (always be true in the case the file gets read). How is `yazi != null` ever going to change to the opposite result if you don't do anything with its value inside the while loop? If you want to read all lines you need to keep looping until the stream reader says it has no further contents.

Comment: Look at the example here to see how to read until the end; it uses `Peek` to determine if there is are any more contents in the buffer. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.readline(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 2):

You are reading it line by line and keep overwriting richTextBox1 with the next line... try:

```
richTextBox1.Text = "";
while (yazi != null)
{
    richTextBox1.Text += yazi;
    yazi = sw.ReadLine();
}
```

Or, if you don't need to parse each line, you can read it all in one go:

```
if (File.Exists("metinbelgesi.txt"))
{
    richTextBox1.Text = File.ReadAllText("metinbelgesi.txt");
}
```

Comment: Just for completeness, `x += y` is equal to `x = x + y` [C# Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/addition-assignment-operator) this means, you _append_ the line instead of _replacing_ (re-assigning) it.

Comment: _"You are reading it line by line and keep overwriting richTextBox1 with the next line"_ with the code from question: No he is not. He is reading the first line and setting the text property with _that_ line forever (if it not null, that is). Which has me thinking it's not the actual code.

Comment: Yeah, I figured he had removed the code that reads and processes the next line since he ends up with the last line in the file and only needed the "+=" part.

Answer (score 2):

According to your code, you're only reading the first line.  There should be a `ReadLine()` statement inside your loop as well.

Pay attention that you will always overwrite the contents of the textbox with the line of text you've just read.
So, when you've finished your loop, only the last line that you've read will occur in the textbox.

For simplicity, you can also have a look at the `File` class and more specifically the [ReadAllLines()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-be/library/system.io.file.readalllines(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

Answer (score -1):

You should probaby try to make your life easier by using some of the simpler `File` operations.

Try this instead:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    File.AppendAllText("metinbelgesi.txt", $"{textBox1.Text} {textBox2.Text} {textBox3.Text}.");
}

private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (File.Exists("metinbelgesi.txt"))
    {
        richTextBox1.Text = File.ReadAllText("metinbelgesi.txt");
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("First, You Join.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Life will be easier, and there will be a performance problem.

Comment: I have effectively posted the similar answer to @IAmCoder - he's got 2 reps and I've got -2. That's weird.

Comment: @Enigmativity: Imagine a scenario where you have a file with millions of lines which you will probably use for data mining. You'd want get each line and pass it to another for process (i.e. cleaning, etc.) and then at the same time proceed to another line, instead of filling your memory up with all data first and then even use more memory for pre-analysis.

Comment: @Arrrr: Excellent explanation.

Comment: @Arrrr - Yes, but the OP is loading the text in a `RichTextBox` - that's a different scenario.

Comment: @Enigmativity: There will another problem too, in case the file is in use by another process, `File.ReadAllText` will fail. About my downvote, a user like you who has nearly 70K reputation is expected to provide a more detailed answer, at least include the downsides of `File` operations and I'll change my downvote to an upvote.

Comment: @Arrrr "Imagine a scenario where you have a file with millions of lines" - in _that_ case you are doing it wrong anyway. Keeping millions of lines in a file instead of a DB is an architectural flaw in the first place. So while your objection is somehow valid, it is merely academic and I (in this case) would dismiss it as premature optimization.

Comment: @Fildor: It is a flaw for conventional systems but it's very common in data mining projects.

Comment: @Fildor: That's right, this isn't, but the scenario I was describing was. So you can't say a large file is a flawed scenario.

Comment: @Arrrr I just did :D No, seriously. I don't want to argue. I hereby officially correct my statement to saying "Keeping millions of lines in a file instead of a DB is an architectural flaw in the first place , _except in a data mining context_" - But still this is completely irrelevant for OP's question and Enig's answer.

Comment: @Fildor: Of course nobody want's to rely on a text file instead of a database in commercial system, but the reason why it is common in DM projects is that, the data is is deadly huge to a point that SQL DBMS will take over minutes to insert a new row, and No-SQL dbs even Mongo will fail to properly handle the data. The data may also come from parties that may not be expert and it may be erroneous, full of problems, different schema on each row, full of noise, etc. That's why a text file would be a better data source. But I 100% agree with your statement.

Comment: @Arrrr Ok - we agree. And I don't want to argue about _one_ downvote. If you think it is justified - so be it. I don't; although I do see your point in a way.

Comment: @Arrrr - It is also expected that an answer be targeted to match the capabilities of the OP. In this case the OP just needs a nudge to be able to explore this option. Besides, this code is kind of self explanatory.